# Getting script from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to integrate an api into my webpage, what is the equivalent of

```
<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in javascript or jquery?

Comment: What's wrong with `<script>`?

Comment: i guess you didnt search, there must be lots of questions which answers your question..!

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you use [`JQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

```
$.getScript(yourUrl, yourCallback);
```